# Cython interfaced with C++: segmentation fault for large arrays

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, cython

I am transferring my code from Python/C interfaced using ctypes to Python/C++ interfaced using Cython. The new interface will give me an easier to maintain code, because I can exploit all the C++ features and need relatively few lines of interface-code.

The interfaced code works perfectly with small arrays. However it encounters a *segmentation fault* when using large arrays. I have been wrapping my head around this problem, but have not gotten any closer to a solution. I have included a minimal example in which the segmentation fault occurs. Please note that it consistently occurs on Linux and Mac, and also valgrind did not give insights. Also note that the exact same example in pure C++ does work without problems.

The example contains (part of) a Sparse matrix class in C++. An interface is created in Cython. As a result the class can be used from Python.

## C++ side

`sparse.h`

```
#ifndef SPARSE_H
#define SPARSE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

class Sparse {

  public:
    int* data;
    int  nnz;

    Sparse();
    ~Sparse();
    Sparse(int* data, int nnz);
    void view(void);

};

#endif
```

`sparse.cpp`

```
#include "sparse.h"

Sparse::Sparse()
{
  data = NULL;
  nnz  = 0   ;
}

Sparse::~Sparse() {}

Sparse::Sparse(int* Data, int NNZ)
{
  nnz  = NNZ ;
  data = Data;
}

void Sparse::view(void)
{

  int i;

  for ( i=0 ; i<nnz ; i++ )
    printf("(%3d) %d\n",i,data[i]);

}
```

## Cython interface

`csparse.pyx`

```
import  numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

# UNCOMMENT TO FIX
#from cpython cimport Py_INCREF

cdef extern from "sparse.h":
  cdef cppclass Sparse:
    Sparse(int*, int) except +
    int* data
    int  nnz
    void view()


cdef class PySparse:

  cdef Sparse *ptr

  def __cinit__(self,**kwargs):

    cdef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1, mode="c"] data

    data = kwargs['data'].astype(np.int32)

    # UNCOMMENT TO FIX
    #Py_INCREF(data)

    self.ptr = new Sparse(
      <int*> data.data if data is not None else NULL,
      data.shape[0],
    )

  def __dealloc__(self):
    del self.ptr

  def view(self):
    self.ptr.view()
```

`setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build   import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
  "csparse",
  sources=["csparse.pyx", "sparse.cpp"],
  language="c++",
)))
```

## Python side

```
import numpy as np
import csparse

data = np.arange(100000,dtype='int32')

matrix = csparse.PySparse(
  data = data
)

matrix.view() # --> segmentation fault
```

To run:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
$ python example.py
```

*Note that `data = np.arange(100,dtype='int32')` does work*.

Comment: Far too much code. Where's your [MCVE]?

Comment: OK "Lightness Races in Orbit", you've got a point! I have stripped everything which was unnecessary

Comment: A solution seems to be to increase the number of references to the array (added as comments in ``csparse.pyx``). However, I think that I have effectively ruined part of Python's power...

Comment: Maybe but you have to remember that your Python is just an interface to a program that's fundamentally written in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory is being managed by your numpy arrays. As soon as they go out of scope (most likely at the end of the `PySparse` constructor) the arrays cease to exist, and all your pointers are invalid. This applies to both large and small arrays, but presumably you just get lucky with small arrays.

You need to hold a reference to all the numpy arrays you use for the lifetime of your `PySparse` object:

```
cdef class PySparse:

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  cdef Sparse *ptr
  cdef object _held_reference # added

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  def __cinit__(self,**kwargs):
      # ....
      # your constructor code code goes here, unchanged...
      # ....

      self._held_reference = [data] # add any other numpy arrays you use to this list
```

As a rule you need to be thinking quite hard about who owns what whenever you're dealing with C/C++ pointers, which is a big change from the normal Python approach. Getting a pointer from a numpy array *does not* copy the data and it *does not* give numpy any indication that you're still using the data.

---

**Edit note:** In my original version I tried to use `locals()` as a quick way of gathering a collection of all the arrays I wanted to keep. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to include to `cdef`ed arrays so it didn't manage to keep the ones you were actually using (note here that `astype()` makes a copy unless you tell it otherwise, so you need to hold the reference to the copy, rather than the original passed in as an argument).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This thought had occurred to me. However, I hoped that Cython would take care of increasing and decreasing the number of references to Python/NumPy variables. As far as I have understood, this is one of the big advantages of Cython over writing the API yourself. The mystery is unfortunately not solved... The segmentation fault persists.

Comment: Unfortunately, the closer you get to C the less Cython can do for you (in terms of avoiding memory management). It has no way of knowing if you use the pointers once in the `Sparse` constructor (which would have been safe) or keep them for future use, which was dangerous. See edit for your second issue.

Comment: Thanks once more. However, I'm quite sure that your second edit is only partly correct. The type ``int`` (and ``int*``) is 32 bit on most architectures, also with 64-bit compilers. Only the ``long int`` (and ``long long int``) types are 64-bit. There are many posts on this (e.g. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-port64/). On my architecture ``int`` is for sure 32-bit.

Comment: You're right about `int`s - my mistake (I've removed that bit of answer)! I'll try to have another look later.

Comment: @Tom Third time lucky (see edit). I'd got the the source of the problem right, but `locals()` didn't quite do what I thought it did.

Comment: We have converged indeed. Thanks!