# Display the percentage of colored portions on the level Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the example I have taken from the sample sets of the matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence
fig = plt.Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
p1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, yerr=menStd)
p2 = ax.bar(ind, womenMeans, width,
             bottom=menMeans, yerr=womenStd)

for p in ax.patches:
    width, height = p.get_width(), p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    ax.annotate('{:.0%}'.format(height), (p.get_x()+.15*width, p.get_y() + height + 0.01))
    
    
plt.show()
```

The reference is available here : [Example in Docs](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py)
Successfully got the following figure:
[image: output image]

I want to know how I can show the percentage of the orange bar and the blue bar just above their levels?

I have already tried the solution from this: [Display percentage above bar chart in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080991/display-percentage-above-bar-chart-in-matplotlib)
Still there is nothing I see.
Let me clarify what I want in advance, I want to display the percentage of the blue portion just above the level of it and the orange portion just above it. I hope I am clear.

Comment: Why do you use `plt.Figure`? Replacing that line and the one with `...subplot(111)` with `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` fixes the problem.

Comment: I have setup my other structure in the similar fashion. Hence I try to replicate it with the example here.

Comment: Jaffer, I got a notification of your comment (although I'm not sure why StackOverflow decided to notify me, you did not tag me). I cannot speak for the two downvoters, but I just wanted to get the negative feeling away. Sometimes the dynamics of the site are just not what you expect, but you really shouldn't take it personally or have continued thoughts about it.

Comment: When I started using Cython I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811538/cython-interfaced-with-c-segmentation-fault-for-large-arrays) that more experienced users probably found too trivial: it got downvoted twice. But for me the question was very much real, I Googled a lot before asking and asked a colleague, and the answer really allowed me to advance.

Comment: @TomdeGeus This isn't first time sir. I can understand there are certain time, I miss something , which I recognize and even apologize for it and make it correct. But this time, I do not see whats wrong. I do not understand what is the issue. I guess Stackoverflow must also penalize people for downvoting questions then they will regret doing it unnecessarily.

Comment: As to your question, one can only guess. My feeling is that your question can come across as if you didn't really investigate. Rather you found an example online and you wanted to have it customised. (I partly base my gut-feeling on the comment you left almost immediately after asking, that comes across a bit as if you are a customer of a service). But again, one can only guess. Don't feel bad, don't take it personally.

Comment: Jaffer, "I guess Stackoverflow must also penalize people for downvoting questions then they will regret doing it unnecessarily". As I said. Please don't take downvotes personally. They happen. Also try not to infer, you don't know if the downvoters regretted. Maybe they did have good reasons, that they stand by. I agree, without comments one can only guess, but still.

Comment: @TomdeGeus Thank you for clarifying. But what you said is not what I tried. I have even given the sample I tried. Even tried harder to check and execute what I found after a lot of searching. If I am not getting the proper result and I have doubts then I ask it here. If StackOverflow is not for help then what for it is?

Comment: . Please keep asking and answering. These two downvotes will disappear from your memory in no time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping over the values in `menMeans` and `womenMeans` should give you what you desire:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
p1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, yerr=menStd)
p2 = ax.bar(ind, womenMeans, width,
             bottom=menMeans, yerr=womenStd)

for id, men in enumerate(menMeans):
    ax.text(id, men+3, str('{}\%'.format(men)))
    ax.text(id, men+womenMeans[id]+3, str('{}\%'.format(womenMeans[id])))
```

If you wanted the total percentage to be plotted on top of the women's bars, instead of the women's percent, you would do:

```py
for id, men in enumerate(menMeans):
    ax.text(id, men+3, str('{}\%'.format(men)))
    ax.text(id, men+womenMeans[id]+3, str('{}\%'.format(womenMeans[id]+men)))
```

[image]

Comment: What I can write in format to get value upto 2 decimal? Get very large values.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with: ```ax.text(id, men+3, str('{:0.2f}\%'.format(men)))```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know